# SQL Server 2014 MSDN License

Tags: sql-server, msdn

I have a Windows 2008 Server which I use for my own applications, services and testing.

Can I use a MSDN license for SQL Server 2014 for testing and my own applications?

I don't earn money with my programs and they are only for myself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **licensing** - not programming. Please ask a Microsoft representative for a definitive answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN licence covers development and testing only.

For running in production environment you can use free Express edition of SQL Server.

Comment: Right but i woud say that this is no production environment or ?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, and don't work for MS. I'd just use express ed if wanted to be compliant.